# Calculator using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and C# and I have to make a calculator with buttons for the number. How can I pass the values of the buttons from the view to the controller? Is there any source code that I can use?

Here is the buttons table in the view

```
<form name="Cal">
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td width="65%" align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="Input" size="20" onchange="FixValue()">
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="65%" align="center">
                    <input type="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="two" value="2" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="three" value="3" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="plus" value="+" onclick="Operate(this.value)">
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" name="four" value="4" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="five" value="5" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="six" value="6" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="minus" value="-" onclick="Operate(this.value)">
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" name="seven" value="7" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="eight" value="8" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="nine" value="9" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="multiply" value="*" onclick="Operate(this.value)">
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" name="Clr" value="c" onclick="AllClear()">
                    <input type="button" name="zero" value="0" onclick="f1(this.value)">
                    <input type="button" name="answer" value="=" onclick="Calculate()">
                    <input type="button" name="divide" value="/" onclick="Operate(this.value)">
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to send a request to the server every time you click on a buttton OR do you want to create your calculation expression and only send a request to the server when you click on "="

Comment: just when clicking the =

Comment: then call a different function when clicking the numbers, and jquery ajax call in a function for the "=" button.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use JavaScript you can call your action directly like this using anonymous object in `Url.Action`:

```
<input type="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController", new { value = 1 })'">
```

Here is C# code for controller:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(int value)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: and this pass the value directly to the controller !!

Comment: @LanaAbusabha I updated the code, forgot about anonymous object, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to pass a value to the controller, you probably want to use jQuery's `$.get` or `$.post`.

E.g. your f1 might look like:

```
function f1(object) {
     $.get('/Calculator/DoButtonPostBack?Button=' + $(object).val());
}
```

And your controller might look like:

```
public class CalculatorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoButtonPostBack(string button)
    {
        //do sometihng
    }
}
```

You would probably want to write the calculator in JavaScript only in most cases though.

Comment: i don't want to write it in JavaScript , i have already done it with it  .